# contrast curves problems

Tags: discrete-signals

I am doing some tests about local/global contrast algorithms and need a simple equation to define an arbitrary S-shaped contrast curve. It's simple if the turning point is assumed to be (0.5, 0.5), but couldn't find a straight equation if the turning point has to be arbitrarily set.

These are the typical contrast curves I achieved for turning point in the middle (0.5, 0.5):
[image]

And the simple equations follow this rule:

y = x^2*2 for x<=0.5

y = 1-(1-x)^2*2 for x>0.5

I would like to be able to allocate the turning point to any (x,y) position and still have a smooth S-shaped curve where the slope is continuous on both sides of the turning point. I would like to keep the equation as simple and straightforward as possible, avoiding the use of splines or any other more complex math.

Any ideas? I tried to google I found some equation like this.

y = [ (1-s)*x + s*a*(x/a)^E ] ^ ( log(b)/log(a) )

Parameters:
(a,b): turning point

s: slope at ends

E: contrast strength

But it does not work like this

[image]

Would you please let me know how do I make the equation like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way is to utilize [Bezier curves](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25237/Bezier-Curves-Made-Simple) (or [Catmull Rom splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Catmull.E2.80.93Rom_spline)). This way, you could define the control points in the way you like. Positioning of the control points would then allow you to adjust the histogram to the desired output.

I would suggest Catmull Rom splines if you want them to pass through the control points. It gives you better control over the curve behavior. Use 5 such points: 2 for the end points, 1 for the middle, and 1 on each side of the center to give you certain curvature.

---

If you don't want to use splines, the black curve looks like a Sigmoid function, while the yellow is a third order polynomial.

You can checkout [this code](https://code.google.com/p/colorhistogram/) to see different implementations.

---

If you are keen on using Logistic family, then I would suggest the generalized logistic growth curve with horizontal asymptotes at $−1$ and $1$:

$y(t)=-1+\frac{2}{[1+ke^{-\beta t}]^{1/v}}$

where $k > 0$, $β > 0$ and $ν > 0$. The parameter $k$ can be adjusted by a time shift, $β$
corresponds to a scaling of time; $ν$ is the key parameter that determines the shape of the
growth, the asymmetry depending on whether it is less than or greater than $1$. This formula reduces to the standard logistic growth for $ν = 1$, $k = 1$, $β = 2$. The *turning point* you refer to is commonly known as the inflection point, where the derivative changes sign.

This is explained in detail [Ayse Humeyra's article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.4839.pdf) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function). Here is a MATLAB code:

```
function [y]= general_logistic(t, k, beta, v)
y = -1 + 2./((1+k*exp(-beta.*t)).^(1./v));
end
```

---

Finally, in [Dino Dini's blog](https://dinodini.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/normalized-tunable-sigmoid-functions/), he explains the normalized tunable sigmoid functions. There, the solution to your problem is addressed. Moreover, a similar question is already posted and [answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459872/adjustable-sigmoid-curve-s-curve-from-0-0-to-1-1). Last but not least, polynomial shaping functions, which would serve the same necessities are discussed in [Golan Levin's page](http://www.flong.com/texts/code/shapers_poly/).

I hope all these would help.

Comment: Sorry, I have already said and you can see that I want to avoid complex math.

Comment: Do you think that sigmoid or a third order polynomial is more complex than the hand crafted log expressions stated above?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it does depend on what we use equation.

Comment: Check my updated response.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm working on this problem, and have found a smooth solution for both contrasting and decrontrasting.

The only problem i have: they are two formulas y= and x=

And **i need to combine them into one y= formula**

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/homar30r84

X formula desmos code :

```
x=\left(\left(\frac{y+1}{2}\right)^{\left(-b\cdot\left(a-b\right)\right)}\right)-\left(\left(\frac{-y+1}{2}\right)^{\left(b\cdot\left(b-a\right)\right)}\right)\left\{-1\le y\le1\right\}
```

Y formula desmos code :

```
y=\left(\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{\left(-b\left(a-b\right)\right)}\right)-\left(\left(\frac{-x+1}{2}\right)^{\left(b\left(b-a\right)\right)}\right)\left\{-1\le x\le1\right\}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/46005)